# What are the ways to insert & retrieve BLOB data from Oracle database using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I've tried to insert BLOB data with SQL developer. But I can't find the insert statements which are actually used to insert BLOB data.

Apart from that, the database speed is really slow. For small files, it executes fine. But when I tried to import 50 mb avi file into BLOB, it took 3-4 minutes & still it was not completed. When I tried to export the BLOB data to a file, exporting process was also slow. I was using Oracle 10g Express Edition. If the database speed is slower than even file-system speed, then why database are used for storing BLOB data? Is there any other way to optimize the performance?

Comment: I never recommend using BLOBS to store files - just put them on a filesystem and store references to those files...

Comment: I would think that `BLOB`s would be almost always stored in the file system and a pointer to the data directory is defined in the `dba_directories` (like metadata). Oracle provides some functions in its `webutil` package to insert `BLOB`s into a table but then those would be in context to users uploading a file (say `.avi`) via a from end application (based on `Oracle Forms` or `Apex` etc.). The other way would be to use `dbms_lob.fileopen` & `dbms_lob.loadfromfile` to initialize your `BLOB` var and then perform the insert but again performance is a concern here.

Comment: @NWest If you're recommending to store BLOB in file-system, then why every professional web application uses robust database as back-end service? If anyone stores major part of my data in file-system, then why at all anyone will need a database? They can store informations in just xml or mdb file & retrieve them when required!!!!

Comment: @DebadyutiMaiti Use the right tool for the right job. BLOBs are *not* for relational data - if you are storing XML in a BLOB you're doing it wrong. Databases are for data that's relational, and can be presented to users in many ways. A filesystem is for storing objects where the data inside those objects is independent of other objects. BLOBS have a rare use case where you might want to store character data that's larger than a VARCHAR2, or binary data that's specific to a certain row, but in a general use case such as yours where you are storing Video Files in a BLOB, just use a filesystem.

Comment: Unlike all the others, I do think that storing BLOBs in the database makes sense (not always but there are some very good reasons to do so). Saving 50mb should **not** take 3-4 minutes. On my pretty old desktop it takes about 8seconds using JDBC. So I guess it's either something with your code or your network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should **expect** storing BLOBs in a database to be (sometimes a bit, often significantly) slower, but definitly not faster than storing them in a file system. The reasons to store them in a DB do not center about performance, but about e.g.:

- Unavailability of a (shared) file system in a clustered or load-balanced scenario
- Ease of backup: Single process, a.o.t. 2 processes when files and DB are used
- Transaction safety: A BLOB is either there and complete or not, but not in a half-baked stage
- others I can't think of right now.

The general rule of thumb is, that if none of these concern you, you should store your files as  ... files. Storing the metadata and pathname in a DB is IMHO good and common practice.

Concerning Oracle tuning: There are books written about that. I suspect to total them far over a ton in dead-tree-paperback format. You might first of all look at the Oracle process' memory consumption - rule of thumb: If it is less than a gig and you use BLOBs, you are in trouble. Read up on the different memory pools and how to increase them. Some limits for the express edition might apply.

Comment: Sometimes you want to be able to access the (exact) same file from different machines in different locations. If you have one central DB it could be a good solution (otherwise you'll have to sync each file to all the machines and deal with possible sync issues).

Comment: @alfasin: This is exactly what the first bullet covers: *Unavailability of a (shared) file system*. In effect you replace a file system with a database.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a code you can use with your sql-developer, it's Java code that uses a StringBuffer in order to INSERT a blob. Hope it will be useful:

```
private void addBlob(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection oracleConn, StringBuffer content) throws Exception
{    
      PreparedStatement st = null;
      try {                
            oracle.sql.BLOB blob = oracle.sql.BLOB.createTemporary(oracleConn, true, oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

            blob.setBytes(1, content.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

            st = oracleConn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO MYTABLE (id, content) VALUES (MYTABLE_S.NEXTVAL, ?)");
            st.setBlob(1, blob);
            st.execute();
            st.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            utils.writeLog("Blob insertion Failed", e, utils.ERR);
            throw e;
        }        
        finally{
            st.close();
        }
  }
```