# How insert mp3 file into oracle database

Tags: oracle

I'm useing java to write some programe,
I need to insert some file into database such as ".mp3,  .wav" files.

by the way how insert these file into oracle database?

Comment: Do you really need to store it inside the database? What about on disk and then file reference to it in the database.

Comment: My boss do not allow me to keep these files on disk so ...

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219734/what-are-the-ways-to-insert-retrieve-blob-data-from-oracle-database-using-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered just storing the MP3 metadata and file location.  I worked on a image server years ago and we attempted storing the images inside the database.  It was much faster to just hand off the file location to the server service requesting it, then it would fetch the file.  It is possible to load the mp3 binary file into a the database as a BLOB if you really want to.